# how do I compare dates with non date type fields in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

my query is as follows:

```
select id,
       date 
  from table 
 where date < '1/31/2015' && date > '11/31/2011'
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `TABLE.date` column?  The CREATE TABLE statement would clarify things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you provide the date as a string, some formats will be implicitly/automatically converted to the proper data type of the column being compared.  IE:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.date
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.date < '2015-01-31'
   AND t.date > '2011-11-31'
```

The safest means of converting a date/time in a string to a DATETIME is to use the [MySQL's STR_TO_DATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
 WHERE t.date < STR_TO_DATE('1/31/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
   AND t.date > STR_TO_DATE('11/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Do note that `STR_TO_DATE` is going to require a calculation for every row of your table. Indexes will be useless and it'll take a long time on large data sets.

Comment: @ceejayoz: You have it backwards - indexes on are the column, not the string value being converted.  Nor is this a RBAR (row by agonizing row) conversion of the string value into a date...

Comment: If the user's dates are stored as strings like "1/31/2015", indexing them isn't going to be much use for filtering by date, and you're going to have to run each `t.date` value through `STR_TO_DATE` to get it into a native format.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Rather than make assumptions, *ask the OP what the data type(s) are*.  You seem to be more interested in hounding me than answering the question.

Comment: If he's querying like that, it's likely that the data is stored like that.

Comment: It looks like this may be a possibilty: so you're saying that if using a non date field type, if the correct date format is used, mysql will convert the field type to date for this calculation? If so would it not then be possible to use BETWEEN on fields that are not date in field type but date in value?

Comment: And Yes it will work: select t.id from table t where t.non_date_field BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2015-01-01'

Comment: @InnateDev: MySQL's implicit data conversion depends on the data type of the column being compared to - if `t.date` is DATETIME, MySQL will try to convert '1/31/2015' into a DATETIME (assuming an accepted format for the data type).  You have to use explicit conversion (IE: STR_TO_DATE) if the format doesn't match, and/or use explicit conversion to change the column data type for comparison (IE: `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t.date, '%m/%d/%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('1/31/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')`)

Comment: @InnateDev: `t.non_date_field BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2015-01-01'` works because it's evaluating **strings**, not *dates*. Check the data, you'll likely find Oct/Nov/Dec is missing from results.

Comment: Is using a date field type preferable or faster than STR_TO_DATE?

Comment: @InnateDev: Using the appropriate data type is always preferable.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL `DATE` and `DATETIME` fields are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. If you didn't use a built-in data type that handles dates, you're going to have a lot more trouble.

Comment: On top of that, I'd just mention that there's a STR_TO_DATE function to convert a string to a valid SQL date.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, && is not the "and" operator in SQL; use AND.

Secondly, MySQL dates are always ISO-8601. I suggest you read the standard or look at some examples.

Thirdly, you can use the SQL function BETWEEN to find a value in a range.

I recommend reading

a) The MySQL documentation

b) Some examples

And

c) Go on a training course, SQL for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think you're wrong on the first point: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and and I WISH I could use a built in data type, which would make BETWEEN and all the other date functions possible. I'm using a longtext type to store these dates hence the rather simple question which now I think youll see makes so much more sense - my bad.